# Renommer par, en, avec ou à

Tags: grammaire

Imaginons-nous avons une liste de prénoms de personnes, et je voudrais demander à quelqu'un de renommer le prénom "X" au prénom "Y", quelle est la proposition la plus correcte.

- Renommer le prénom "X" à "Y"
- Renommer le prénom "X" en "Y"
- Renommer le prénom "X" avec "Y"
- Renommer le prénom "X" par "Y"

Merci

Comment: https://www.franceinter.fr/societe/changer-de-prenom-c-est-desormais-beaucoup-plus-facile changement de prénom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En fait ce qu'on renomme ce n'est pas le prénom mais la personne. Le prénom, lui, on le modifie.

Ce qui me semble le plus naturel est de n'utiliser aucune préposition, et c'est ce qui semble le plus courant aussi. Je pense qu'on peut transposer pour les prénoms ce qui se passe pour les noms de rue et on trouve de nombreux exemples sur [cette page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_anciens_noms_de_voies_de_Paris) donnant la liste des voies de Paris ayant changé de nom. Un exemple dans la presse :

> la rue Adolphe-Thiers a été renommée Louise-Michel. ([Actu.fr](https://actu.fr/normandie/bernay_27056/a-bernay-la-rue-adolphe-thiers-debaptisee-et-renommee-louise-michel_40330128.html))

De la même façon je dirais « renomme X : Y ».

Si vraiment une préposition devait être utilisée ce serait *en*. Si vraiment tu tiens à parler du prénom tu pourrais dire : « modifie X en Y ».

*Par* serait peut-être compréhensible mais ça ne me semble pas idiomatique. Par contre, si on change de verbe, on peut dire « remplace le prénom X par le prénom Y » (merci @jlliagre). Quant à *à* et *avec* je pense qu'il faut les exclure. *À* n'aurait pas de sens et *avec* aurait un tout autre sens, ça voudrait dire que les deux personnes doivent être renommées en même temps.

Comment: Ta réponse est bien sûr complète. Une question seulement. Dois-je effacer ma réponse ?

Comment: @Dimitris Je ne vois pas pourquoi tu effacerais ta réponse. Tu pourrais même avoir des votes positifs. Ta réponse n'est pas ridicule, moi je ne mettrais pas de préposition, mais peut-être que d'autres ne sont pas du même avis, wait & see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I really appreciate it:-)!

Comment: Nice question about a verb whose meaning has evaluated https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renommer

Comment: Cf. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/renommer a nice example that Cnrtl needs an update:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris What do you mean by "evaluated". After you wrote the next comment I wonder if you did not mean "evolve? The TLF is not meant to be updated, it was stopped in 1994, so nearly 30 years ago, lots happen to the language in 30 years !

Comment: Sorry! I should have written evolved as you pointed out. I was about to prepare an assignment (pour une évaluation:-)!) when I was writing the comment.

Comment: J'ajouterais: *Remplacer (le prénom) X par (le prénom) Y*.

Comment: On French websites, when people change their first names, they use the noun changement. Alors, pourquoi pas changer?

Comment: @Lambie Parce que *changer le prénom X en prénom Y* n'est pas idiomatique. Ça ressemble à un tour de prestidigitation.

Comment: Thank you so mush guys, your are an amzing community.

Comment: @jlliagre N'empêche qu'on voit changement de prénom/nom et changer son prénom.nom. Je n'ai pas mis de préposition **exprès**. Je laisse ça aux francophones.

Comment: @Lambie C'est tout à fait exact, on dit bien *changement de nom*. J'expliquais simplement pourquoi *changer* n'était pas une bonne idée dans le cadre de la question qui porte sur un choix de préposition.

Comment: @Lambie Changer de prénom/changement de prénom (de nom) est du vocabulaire lié à une démarche d'état-civil. « L'officier d'état-civil a effectué un changement de prénom ». On ne dira pas « Paul a changé le prénom Paul pour le prénom Paulette », ce n'est pas idiomatique (et avec « en » comme l'a dit jlliagre c'est un tout autre sens). On dirait quelque chose comme : « Paul a fait changer son prénom, elle s'appelle désormais Paulette ». Dans le contexte de la question je ne trouve pas idiomatique de dire  « change le prénom "X" pour "Y" ». Mais libre à toi d'ajouter une réponse.

Comment: @None Je laisse ça aux francophones.

Answer (score 2):

Non native speaker but I would pick up the second sentence as the most natural.

> Renommer le prénom "X" en "Y".

Comment: Yes, that's the right preposition with *renommer* but as None stated, you can't rename an name.